# Different sets of projects to build in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We have about 40 C# projects in our solution.
VS needs a too long time to build the solution. So I set only a small part of projects to be build in Build->Configuration Manager.
And sometimes when I changed something in a project that is not checked to be built I start Build->Batch Build where I select all projects to be built.
So I have two build-sets.

Now my question: Is it possible to define more build-sets in any way? So I can define some build-sets and can easy switch to that which I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Build-->Configuration Manager, and on the top left you will see the ComboBox with the Solution Configurations. There you can just select "New" and create a new build configuration where not all projects are build. Remember to uncheck "Create new Project configurations".

By the way: if you need to rebuild a single project, you can also rightclick that project, select "Build" and it will build even if it's not selected in the solution configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood correctly or not.. But following is what I understood.

You can surely go to Build-Config manager, and define N number of build settings to be created. In top right drop down you can create a new and edit existing configuration..

Hope this helps!!